# Draggable attached to droppable, then draggable coming from some where else

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I dropped an element in droppable area which is attached to the droppable area, then it should be dropped there only but the element is coming from top of the screen.

```
$('.fr12drag').draggable({ 
    containment: ".class",
    revert: true,           
    revertDuration: 400,
    drag: function(event, ui){
        $('#id').hide();
    }
});

$('.fr12drop').droppable({
    drop: function(event,ui) {
        ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
        var left = 0, top = 0;

        left =  parseInt($(this).css("left"))
        top = parseInt($(this).offset().top);

        ui.draggable.css('cursor', 'auto');
        ui.draggable.position({
            my: "center",
            at: "center",
            of: $(this),
            using: function(pos) {
                $(this).animate(pos, "fast", "linear");
            }
        }); 
    }       
});
```

This is the line which i added.

Can check reference in the below link.
https://jsfiddle.net/unjhocog/

Comment: Show the code so that we could look into it.

Comment: that is the only line i added @SorangwalaAbbasali

Comment: Show your full code.

Comment: I added my full code @M.Wiśnicki

Comment: try with this jquery example https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#sortable

Comment: I need in draggable @trusharwidetech